# Sudden break down of Kinect?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using rviz and roboearth when suddenly the image view went black.

The terminal of openni.launch showed a red sentence "depth image frame id does not match rgb image frame id".

I closed the terminal and opened a new one and then roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch but it said "No devices connected... waiting for devices to be connected".

I reboot the computer a few times, sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect, but the problem persists.

Up till this morning the Kinect has been running normally. I really have no idea what happened. Is it due to auto-update? Anyone please help?

Turtlebot laptop: Ubuntu 10.04; ROS Electric

Workstation: Ubuntu 12.04; ROS Fuerte (I have another one in Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS Electric. I tried but the problem remains unsolved.)

The Kinect shows a flashing green light. But when I type lsusb, I saw only one device from Microsoft and one from Chronicity. Is it normal or not?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60372/sudden-break-down-of-kinect???/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on 2013-04-09**:
Remove USB and restart and connect back only when you do rviz. I had the same problem.

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-04-10**:
Thank you very much. I tried that but it still says No devices connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved. Power supply problem from the iRobot Create base.

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0